# "Indirect form" of the sentence

Tags: grammar, spoken-english, direct-speech

**Direct:**

> John said, "Do you know if Tom plays cricket."

**Indirect:**

> John asked me if I know *if Tom plays cricket.*

Is it correct grammartically and in terms of spoken English?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it as "John asked me if I _ knew _ if Tom plays cricket." but it is a fairly tiny difference, and not one that many people would pick up on.

Since 'asked' is past tense, know/knew should be past tense too. Apart from that, it is perfectly normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

Direct: John **said**, "Do you **know** if Tom **plays** cricket?"

Indirect: John **asked** me if I **knew** if Tom **played** cricket.

**[** Direct: John says, "Do you know if Tom plays cricket?"

Indirect: John asks me if I know if Tom plays cricket.**]**